# Multiple inputs having one input to be the output

Tags: c#, dynamic, input

I want to make a simple time calculator having multiple inputs with one input be an output

Example:

INPUTS:
time in:
time out:
estimated hrs:

OUTPUT:
*when I input time in and time out ==> output is estimated hrs
*when I input time in and estimated hrs ==> output is time out
*when I input time out and estimated hrs ==> output is time in

I have no idea how to start other than make a separate textboxes for each input scenario. How do I make just 3 textboxes and make all the ouput scenarios? Even an algorithm is highly appreciated. (coding in c#).

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? SO doesn't write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method

```css
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //textbox1 is estimated hours
            if (textBox1.Text.Count() == 0)
            {
                //*when I input time in and time out ==> output is estimated hrs
                return;
            }
            //textbox2 is time out
            if (textBox2.Text.Count() == 0)
            {
                //*when I input time in and estimated hrs ==> output is time out
 
                return;
            }
            //textbox3 is time in
            if (textBox3.Text.Count() == 0)
            {
                //*when I input time out and estimated hrs ==> output is time in
 
                return;
            }​
```

Comment: I have come up with the above code but I want my application to eliminate the button1_Click (as per code above). Example it automatically detects when I am inputting time in and time out and immediately calculates the estimated hrs as output. And so on..

Comment: Double click the text boxes and an event will be created on the form.  I won't work if somebody copy and paste numbers into the text boxes.